# Get Value into textfield javascript

Tags: javascript, textfield

i have this code, and is working.
But i wanna show this total in textfield or hiddenfield.

```
<script>
    function calculate_total(className, div){
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
            total += parseInt(elements[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
    }
</script>
```

Html

```
<input type="text" name="box1" id="box1" class="addition_textbox" value="4" /><br />
<input type="text" name="box2" id="box2" class="addition_textbox" value="4" /><br />
<input type="text" name="box3" id="box3" class="addition_textbox" value="4" /><br />
<input type="text" name="box4" id="box4" class="addition_textbox" value="4" /><br />
<input type="text" name="box5" id="bo5" class="addition_textbox" value="4" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate Total" onclick="calculate_total('addition_textbox', 'total_text')" /><br />
<div id="total_text"></div>
```

i just wanna show the total value in here `<input type="text" id="here">`

Comment: Use a value instead of innerHTML, like "document.getElementById('here').value = total;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
document.getElementById(textArea).value = "Total: " + total;
```

For `divs` you're using `.innerHTML` and for textfields use `.value` and at the time of calling the function `calculate_total('addition_textbox', 'here')"` pass ID of a textfield as a second argument!

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5yrK/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line in your code:

```
function calculate_total(className, div){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
    total += parseInt(elements[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
  document.getElementById('here').value = total; //add this line
  return false; //add this to prevent the form to submit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
 var reduce=Function.prototype.call.bind([].reduce);
 document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function(){
     var result=reduce(document.querySelectorAll("input[class=addition_textbox]"), function(o,n ){return o+n.value*1}, 0);
     document.querySelector("#total_text").textContent=result;
 });
```

1) bind the *reduce*-Function to `reduce`.

2) bind the click-Event to our summation

3) retrieve all relevant textboxes and reduce the result.

4) display result in `DIV`

Here is the fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cURva/)

Look the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) Entry for compatibility issues.

EDIT: I just saw »i just wanna show the total value in here «

So, you have to adjust Step (4) which should be an easy one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line `document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "Total: " + total;` to `document.getElementById(div).value = "Total: " + total;` can solve your problem..

you can find the use of `.value` here in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp) tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

hey i have created a jsfiddle using your code please go through it...

```
function calculate_total(className, div){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i){
    total += parseInt(elements[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
  //here i am setting the total to the input tag
  document.getElementById("here").value =total;
}
```

see the working example here:-
 http://jsfiddle.net/6YSXC/26/